# Azure devops pipeline job shows success even though the Maven task is failed

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, task, pipeline

I'm getting "Build Success" in the log of Maven task even though the goal task is failure. How to make the job a failure if the task has errors as below? Thanks.

Yaml file:

```
    - task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'integration-test -DskipIntegrationTests=false -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false'
```

Error as below:

```
[Error] Failures:
[Error] <Filename> errror details
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run:2, Failures:2, Errors:0, Skipped:0
[INFO]
[INFO]----------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO]----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The failure of the test methods for your project is not the '**`Standard Error`**'. It just a result report of the test methods for your project, and will not be written to the **`StandardError`** stream. So, the failure does not affect the final status of the task run.

If you want the job fails when the tests fail, as a workaround, you can try to set up a script to check the test result, and write a '**`Standard Error`**' (e.g. **`Exit 1`**) to the **`StandardError`** stream if there is any test fails.